# Count distinct values that meet certain conditions

Tags: sql

I'm working on a table describing the scores students in multiple classes have on multiple exams. What I'm trying to do is to get the number of class with an averaged score over 80. The table looks like the following one:

```
Score_summary
```

| Class | Student | Exam | Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Class_A | Student_1 | Exam_A | 90 |
| Class_A | Student_1 | Exam_B | 0 |
| Class_A | Student_2 | Exam_A | 30 |
| Class_A | Student_2 | Exam_B | 40 |
| Class_B | Student_3 | Exam_A | 100 |
| Class_B | Student_3 | Exam_B | 80 |
| Class_B | Student_4 | Exam_A | 80 |
| Class_B | Student_4 | Exam_B | 90 |

So far I managed to get the table of the classes which meet the condition and their respective average score. Such as:

| Class | Average_Score |
| --- | --- |
| Class_B | 90 |

To get this result, I tried:

```
Select `Score_summary`.`Class` AS `Class`, avg(`Score_summary`.`Score`) AS `Average_Score`
From `Score_summary`
Group by `Class`
Having `Average_Score` > 80
```

And the last step would be counting the distinct number of classes I get. But I'm not sure if I'm thinking this correctly. If yes, then the question would be "Is there a way to Select again after Having?" If not, what would be a proper way doing so?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Add a second level of aggregation.

```
SELECT count(*)
       FROM (SELECT ss.class
                    FROM score_summary ss
                    GROUP BY ss.class
                    HAVING avg(ss.score) > 80) x;
```